# Android SQLite "BETWEEN" not inclusive or returns all records

Tags: android, sqlite, between

Very simple task it would seem, trying to get a given range of records/rows in my SQLite db in Android app with the following :

```
String[] projection = {"_id"};
String selection = "_id between ? and ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"1", "10"};

queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

With the above selectionArgs I'm getting just the two rows, row 1 and 10. If I change arg to anything else I'm getting the whole lot (entire set of records/rows) as if there was no condition. Been banging my head for a day why this works the way it does, perhaps there's some special thing to know about the use of "between" in SQLite ? Any comments/help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
private SQLiteDatabase productDatabase;
   public Cursor get_result(){
   Cursor c;
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName +"WHERE _id BETWEEN" + value1 +"AND" + value2;
   c = productDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
}

Cursor cursor=get_result();
    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
    Log.d("count of product id="+cursor.getString(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem from your side I checked and it works fine,

**Method**

```
public Cursor GetBetween(String[] projection,String selection, String[] args){
        return db.query(TBL_NAME, projection, selection, args, null, null, null);
    }
```

**Implementation**

```
        String[] projection = new String[]{"_id"};
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1","3"};
        String selection = "_id between ? and ?";
        Cursor cursorGetBetween = helper.GetBetween(projection,selection, selectionArgs);
        startManagingCursor(cursorGetBetween);
        cursorGetBetween.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursorGetBetween.isAfterLast()){
            Log.d("value of cursorGetBetween", cursorGetBetween.getString(0));
            cursorGetBetween.moveToNext();
        }
```

**Output**

```
01-31 18:42:58.176: D/value of cursorGetBetween(647): 1
01-31 18:42:58.176: D/value of cursorGetBetween(647): 2
01-31 18:42:58.176: D/value of cursorGetBetween(647): 3
```

Comment: I would but need to return Cursor from my query to populate a list. And yes, I have also tried and used SQLiteDatabase's query and rawQuery methods, both with the same precise results as in my original question.

Comment: oh man.. this only makes it even more mysterious  .. I've tried to actually check how many results does my cursor return, hoping there was some error in the way it displays the results, but it confirms my initial result. I have no idea whatsoever why is it happening .. using precisely the code you have above ..

Comment: OK, solved! for any lost souls who ever encounter this problem and wonder why ... for "between" and most likely all similar grouping queries that work by index, the db needs to actually have constraints and corresponding sequence table ... mine was created outside in the SQLite DB Browser, with tables imported from CSV files and NOT from execution of SQL. Good luck to all!