# How to write A Range Query in Sqlite Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table with 2 fields: `Number` and `Description`, I want to get the description from a number I request.

For example: I request the number 22. But in the database, there is no row matching the value 22.

I need to write a query to get the values **ranges between +5 and -5** of that number and **getting the nearest data** present in the database. That is, I want to get `"rty"` as the description when I request 22.

```
Table

Num     |Description
--------+-----------
25      |ASD
18      |wert
21      |rty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should ideally work. Will return a cursor with all the results from the table.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT Description FROM Table_Name WHERE Num BETWEEN "+(inputNumber-Range)+" AND "+(inputNumber+Range) +"ORDER BY (Num- "+inputNumber+")", null);
```

**Edit:** I am glad the above query works for you.But I think this query is the correct answer to the question you specifically asked

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT Description FROM Table_Name WHERE Num BETWEEN "+(inputNumber-Range)+" AND "+(inputNumber+Range) +"ORDER BY ABS(Num- "+inputNumber+")", null);
```

Taking the absolute value to avoid negative differences

Comment: Just a minor typo, I think the "Price" in `ORDER BY` should be "Num".

Comment: @AndrewT. Oops..sorry.Corrected :)

Comment: Great job! I wanted to recommend using 'abs()' before, but I was diverted to other things and forgot about it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use like this method

```
public Cursor get_result(){
   Cursor c;
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName +"WHERE _id BETWEEN" + value1 +"AND" + value2;
   c = productDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi write a query as follows

```
String query = "SELECT Description FROM Table_Name WHERE Num BETWEEN " + (inputNumber - Range)
            + " AND " + (inputNumber + Range) + "ORDER BY (Price - " + inputNumber + ")";
```

also you  can visit [Android SQLite "BETWEEN" not inclusive or returns all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079875/android-sqlite-between-not-inclusive-or-returns-all-records)